# Conditional questions

Tags: grammar, conditionals

I am confused about the conditionals in English. Why is it necessary to add "had" in the third conditional but not in the second conditional? They are both similar but the difference is that the third conditional talks about the past while the second talks about the future. Also for the third conditional would it be "we hadn't" or "we didn't have"?
For example would I say, " if we hadn't gone to the play, I would have slept more" or If we didn't have gone to the play, I would have slept more".

Comment: *If we didn't have gone to the play...* is syntactically invalid. It's syntactically valid to start a sentence with *If we **didn't go** to the play...*, but that would require a *very* unusual context (probably involving the speaker not actually *knowing* whether he'd been to the play or not, which seems unlikely! :)

Comment: Personally, I don't think these "numbered conditionals" are worth bothering with. There's no such thing as a complete numbered list of all possible conditional structures available in English, and the ones that *have* been assigned numbers can have a variety of different implications determined by the exact context. But in essence, 2nd conditional refers to a hypothetical alternate ***current*** situation ("irrealis"), whereas 3rd conditional refers to something that ***didn't happen*** (a *"hypothetical **past**"*, if you want to call it that, but it's not "irrealis").

Comment: Ok thank you, what about the use of had, why is it necessary that we use had for the third conditional?

Comment: Suppose I drank too much beer last night, so I have a hangover today. I can imagine *not* having drunk too much (even though that's not what happened), and that enables me to say ***If I had** not drunk too much last night, I **would** not have a hangover now*. The general format being *If the Past **had been** different, the Present **would be** different*. For most people, that's just how English works (no special "reason"), but it might help you to think of ***would be*** as a reference to something that's "not Present"....

Comment: ...and sometimes people say English only has two tenses (Present, and "not Present", which is often but not always "Past"). So if you think of things that way with this "3rd conditional" (if the Past ***had been*** different, the Present would *also* be different), it might make sense to you that we use a kind of "hypothetical Past Perfect" to refer to an "unreal Past" coming before an "unreal Present".

Comment: We use the auxiliary *do* with *have* only where the latter has the literal sense of own, hold, possess, etc. We do not use it with the *have* of compound tenses, the ones formed with past participles. Thus, *If they **didn’t have** ice cream, I would have ordered pie*, but *If they **hadn’t offered** ice cream, I would have been disappointed*.

Comment: *why is it necessary that we use had for the third conditional?* Because that's the way the English language evolved, through a variety of random events.